# Not able to click on an <i> element. I am using Firefox driver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried `click() , send_keys(Keys.RETURN),send_keys(Keys.ENTER),send_keys("\n")`. It didn't work. Can any one please help?

```
<thead>

<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>
        <div class="th-floater"></div>
        <i class="icon-chevron-up clickable th-floater"></i>
        <i class="icon-chevron-down clickable th-floater"></i>
    </th>
    <th></th>
    .
    .
    .
</thead>
```

My python code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

flag = False # Keep trying untill page loads and the element is found.

while flag == False:    
  try:
    i_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//thead//th[2]//i[@class='icon-chevron-up clickable th-floater']")

    time.sleep(2)
    i_ele.click()
    flag = True
    print "Element clicked"
  except:
    print "Element not clicked"
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with xpath, but wouldn't `"//thead//tr//th[2]//i[@class='icon-chevron-up clickable th-floater']"` be more correct?

Comment: Yes, I could use that too. However, It is able to identify the element correctly with currnet xpath expression.  I have used                print i_ele.get_attribute("class")  to print the classname and  print i_ele.tag_name  to print the tagname. It prints correctly.

Comment: Confusion is why is it not able to click on the element <i>  ?  Will really appreciate any help on this . I am completely blocked !

Comment: Do you see any kind of exception when you attempt the `.click()`? Well looking at your try/except, you won't see the exception that Webdriver will throw. Try without the try/except and let us know the exception that you see.

Comment: have you tried i[contains(@class,'icon-chevron-up clickable th-floater')]? I've had issues in the past with @class='xxx'

Comment: @ Mark  I see selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not  currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:        but then I added time.sleep(3) before  locationg the element using xpath and now I dont get any exception. Click still does not work.  I also went into python  -i  (interactive mode) and do i_ele.click() . But no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how this solved it. But I guess this is some issue with Win 7 professional.
I reinstalled Python and selenium from scratch but click still  did not work. I reproduced this on another Win 7 Professional machine as well.

After getting frustrated I installed Python and selenium on a windows server machine. Click started working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="icon-chevron-up clickable th-floater"]')
```